# Unable to WRAP_CONTENT RecyclerView inside LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-linearlayout

Basically I have two similar layouts with different approach to create. The problem is that `RecyclerView` `WRAP_CONTENT` behaves differently on those 2 layouts. At the first layout it works fine, while at the others, `WRAP_CONTENT` doesn't work.

The code below doesn't work.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    ... other layout codes
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/xxx"
        style="@style/MarginLeftDetail"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
    />
     ... other layout codes
</LinearLayout>
```

While this is the one that is working.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    ... other layout codes
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/xxx"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/yyy"
        style="@style/MarginLeftDetail"
        android:layout_marginTop="7.5dp"/>
    ... other layout codes
</RelativeLayout>
```

Does `LinearLayout` interpret `WRAP_CONTENT` differently than `RelativeLayout`?

UPDATE : If I wrap the first `RecyclerView` with `RelativeLayout`, it works fine. So I guess `LinearLayout` really interpret `WRAP_CONTENT` differently? Or is it a bug?

Thanks.

Comment: You have to provide more issue details. Can you post screenshot for both linear and relative layout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add `android:layout_weight=1` to `RecyclerView` if you are giving `android:height="0dp"`
Change your code as follow

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    ... other layout codes
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/xxx"
        style="@style/MarginLeftDetail"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight= "1"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
    />
     ... other layout codes
</LinearLayout>
```